# Azure DevOps Pipeline -> Difference between Hosted and Hosted VS 2017

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-hosted-agent

What is the difference between the "Hosted" and the "Hosted VS2017" on azure devops building pipeline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Azure DevOps Pipeline -> Diference between Hosted and Hosted VS 2017

There are a lot of differences between Hosted and Hosted VS 2017, but the main difference are the pre-installed softwares and the running platform.

You can check document [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/blob/master/docs/pipelines/agents/hosted.md) for the details info about [Microsoft-hosted agents.

**Hosted:** [Visual Studio 2015 on Windows Server 2012r2.](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2015-Server2012R2-Readme.md)

**Hosted VS 2017:** [Visual Studio 2017 on Windows Server 2016](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md).

Note: `Visual Studio 2010 SP1`, `Visual Studio SDK 2012 RTM`, `Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate Update 4`, `Visual Studio SDK 2013 RTM`, `Visual Studio 2013 Update 5`, `Visual Studio SDK 2015 RTM`, `Visual Studio 2015 Update 3` are all installed on machines in the Azure Pipelines Hosted pool.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Those links don't quite explain how from `queue: name: Hosted VS2017` you can deduce what kind of image it's mapped to. And vice versa - knowing that you need image `vs2017-win2016`, how do you deduce that queue name should be `Hosted VS2017` and not `vs2017-win2016` or `Hosted vs2017-win2016`. What's the relation between YAML queue name and image name?